# Values of lis and converting them to back to Integers

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the snippet of code below and I am trying to pull the values of each `li` and convert them back to an integer, add them to a number i.e. something like `element += 1`, and then `append` the new values to the existing `li`.

As you can probably tell, my current code comes back as `NaN` in the console. That's because it's trying to `parseInt` the element, which is an array of `lis` not the values of the `lis`.

My question would be how to extract those values of the `lis`?

```
let element = document.createElement('div')

document.body.appendChild(element)

let ul = document.createElement('ul')
 
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li')
  li.innerHTML = (i + 1).toString()
  ul.appendChild(li)
}
 
element.appendChild(ul)

selectedElements = element.querySelector('ul').querySelectorAll('li')
console.log(selectedElements);

selectedElements.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element);
  console.log(parseInt(element));
});
```

```
NodeList(3) [li, li, li]
0: li
1: li
2: li
length: 3
__proto__: NodeList
playground.js:19 <li>​…​</li>​
playground.js:20 NaN
playground.js:19 <li>​…​</li>​
playground.js:20 NaN
playground.js:19 <li>​…​</li>​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to access the text *inside* your `li` elements. You can do this via `textContent` as shown below:

```js
selectedElements.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element);
  console.log(parseInt(element.textContent));
});
```

Comment: Ah...I forgot about those...thanks for helping noob folks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `textContent` to get the text in the element. You can also use the unary plus operator to more simply convert a string to a number.

```
selectedElements.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element);
  console.log(+element.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log(parseInt(element.**innerHTML**));

Comment: `innerHTML` will work but not the best solution in this context. `innerHTML` will return HTML tags as well if they exist. We need to work with the `textContent` this time and parse it into a number